# Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct? What's wrong?

Tags: c#, enums

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace NumbertoWordHamza
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    }
}
private void TextBox1_TextChanged(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Information.IsNumeric(TextBox1.Text)) {
        TextBox2.Text = "";
        return;
    }

    TextBox2.Text = GetTextForNumber(TextBox1.Text);

}
```

I've looked at methods and fields and read about them. I believe I'm misplacing some code? Do I need to add something or remove something? I know it's a stupid mistake.

Comment: Your `TextBox1_TextChanged` method appears not to be part of a type... *all* methods need to be part of a type.

Answer (score 4):

**Problem :** You are writing  `TextBox1_TextChanged` event handler outside your class.

**Solution :** You need to move your `TextBox1_TextChanged` event handler inside the Class `Form1` .

Try This:

```
namespace NumbertoWordHamza
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void TextBox1_TextChanged(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Information.IsNumeric(TextBox1.Text))
            {
                TextBox2.Text = "";
                return;
            }
            TextBox2.Text = GetTextForNumber(TextBox1.Text);
        }   
    }
}
```